# Being able to create two new rows at once

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function insertTwoBlankRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var currentRow = 1;
  //We will loop through each row starting from 1276 and insert two new rows below it
  while (currentRow <= lastRow) {
    //Insert two blank rows below the current row
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(currentRow, 2);
    //Move to the next data row, which is now three rows down due to the inserted rows
    currentRow += 3;
    //Increment the lastRow by 2, as we've added two new rows
    lastRow += 2;
  }
}
```

What this formula can does in app script in google sheets is add two new rows after every third. For example, when this is executed, row 1 will add two new rows underneath of it creating rows 2 and 3. Then after that, for row four, it will have two new rows underneath that creating rows 5 and 6.  What I am needing is to adjust this, currently, this formula only makes two new rows underneath one row one at one time rather then executing it all at once which is what I need it to do.

I tried asking Chatgpt but it said that is not possible because the API will not allow it to create two new rows at once. Can someone please help me out with my request?

Comment: Is it correct to say then that you are attempting to separate all of the current rows of data with two new rows?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am trying to get this code to add two new rows to all of them like discussed before.

Comment: Did I make any mistakes in rewriting your function?

Comment: So it is still not executing all at once. It works but it is still doing it one by one rather then all at once

Comment: I don't know.  I just rewrote it so that it would be easier to read for other users.

Comment: Just one more question.  Does your spreadsheet utilize cell forumulas?

Comment: I'm thinking you might be able to create all the rows at one time if you create them in an array.  But I'm not sure I'd wish to tackle that if you are using formulas in your spreadsheets.  I'm guesing the spreadsheet duplicates the formula as it inserts one row at a time, which may take longer but it also accomplishes more and ends up with a more useful solution to all.

Comment: How do you execture this function, menu, button?

Comment: @TheWizEd, what do you mean by that

Comment: Is your function exectured from a menu option added to the main menu, or is it exectured from a button click or do you just intend to execute from script editor?

Comment: I intend to execute this from script editor. The code you just gave me, I get an error message saying  [TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getLastRow')]. Not sure how to fix it

Comment: Okay I was able to figure out my issue but I had to edit the code you gave me for it to work here is the correct version function insert2Rows() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet20");
    if (!sheet) {
      console.log("Sheet not found");
      return;
    }
    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    while(lastRow > 1) {  // leave row 1 as is
      sheet.insertRows(lastRow, 2);
      lastRow--;
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

Comment: I should note that this new code you gave me is still not making this execute all at once, it is still doing adding two new rows one at a time

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of adding 2 rows between each exiting row.

```
function insert2Rows() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Test");
    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    while( lastRow > 1 ) {  // leave row 1 as is
      sheet.insertRows(lastRow,2);
      lastRow--;
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```